# Is serialization the best way to implement a save game feature in a Django game?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models

I'm writing a simulation game in Django and was wondering what the best way to implement a save game feature would be. I want each user to be able to create, save, and load multiple games independent of other users.

Ideally they would create the game and a preconfigured set of objects would be used initially. As the game progresses, these will obviously be modified (either manually by the user or via the actions taking place in the simulation). I want these changes to be saved automatically, then the user should be able to switch between their various saved games and different information will be presented to them based on which game they decide to load at any particular point in time.

Can this be done with serialization or is there a better way to accomplish this? I know Django has a built-in serialization module so I was thinking of using this.

If serialization is the way to go, what would a basic implementation of this look like? Code examples or just general theory would both be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion based. That being said, note that JSON etc can only serialize primitive objects and Python's built-in [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)s are version dependent; that is, you may not be able to load your previously saved games with a new version of Python. Writing your own saved game serializer circumvents those issues but requires more effort.

Comment: The question is rather broad but I was also looking for a few different options to steer me in the right direction. That's a good point about JSON, I wonder if I can achieve a similar outcome just using the ORM to maintain the data. @Selcuk

Comment: If all game state can be stored in the database that would be the cleanest method.

Comment: Cool, I will give it a shot. Thanks!